# Merge train in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Is it possible to somehow implement a merge train in Azure DevOps, similar to what [GitLab does](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/merge_trains.html)? Or merge queues as it is called in [GitHub](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/configuring-branches-and-merges-in-your-repository/configuring-pull-request-merges/managing-a-merge-queue)?

> Merge train example
>
> Three merge requests (A, B and C) are added to a merge train in order,
> which creates three merged results pipelines that run in parallel:
>
> ```
> The first pipeline runs on the changes from A combined with the target branch.
> The second pipeline runs on the changes from A and B combined with the target branch.
> The third pipeline runs on the changes from A, B, and C combined with the target branch.
> ```

Answer (score 0):

No, Azure DevOps doesn't have a similar feature.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I know that Azure unfortunately doesn't offer it as a feature, but my question was more about getting pointers for how to implement this yourself. For example by using hooks + their API, or similar.

Comment: Its scriptable in Azure pipelines for sure. Grabbing the unmerged PRs with a lower ID that target the same branch should be doable. Then you'll need to script the checkout step yourself or you could potentially checkout from a pre-job decorator.